# How to find a date with a list of specified date ranges in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have an IEnumerable of a class that I created to contain date ranges. That class looks like this:

```
public class Range<T>
    where T: struct 
{
    public T Start { get; set; }
    public T End { get; set; }
}
```

I want to find all the records in my set where a date column falls within ANY of the specified date ranges. This was my attempt:

```
deals = deals.Where(
            deal =>
                criteria.DateRanges.Any(
                  dt =>
                    deal.CloseDate >= dt.Start &&
                    deal.CloseDate < dt.End.Value.AddDays(1)));
```

This throws an error I assume because EF doesn't know how to translate `criteria.DateRanges.Any()` to SQL. So how would you write this to find dates that match ANY of the date ranges?

Comment: If the date ranges are held in memory and not in the database, then if you want to run this query on the database then you're going to need to find a way to send them over. EF doesn't know how to translate your date class into parameters.

Comment: @stuartd, hence the asking of the question

Comment: Well, if I had to ask whether they are in memory, then you haven't explained it very well. How many ranges are there, to an order of magnitude?

Comment: The date ranges are specified by the user. I doubt there would ever be more than 5.

Comment: Dynamically building up a query using IQueryable and [a predicate builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) would be one way

Comment: @adam0101 Do you have the option to use pure SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) for this:

```
var expr = PredicateBuilder.False<Deal>();
foreach(var range in criteria.DateRanges)
   expr = expr.Or(d => dt.CloseDate >= range.Start && dt.CloseDate < range.End);
deals = deals.AsExpandable().Where(expr);
```

Another option would be to use [Expression Trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) but that seems a bit overkill for what you're trying to do.

Comment: This doesn't work w/o `AsExpandable()`. Better use [Universal PredicateBuilder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/).

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks, I forgot the `AsExpandable` while typing the answer, edited in

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @stuartd, if there are a few range conditions you can build your own expression creating one `And` expression per range, and combining them at the end in several `Ors`. You could create a static generic method like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<T,bool>> RangeExpression<T>(string property, IEnumerable<Range<DateTime>> criterias )
{
            Expression result = null;
            ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "o");
            foreach (var item in criterias)
            {
                var value1 = item.Start.Date;
                var value2 = item.End.Date.AddDays(1);

                MemberExpression memberExpression1 = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, property);
                MemberExpression memberExpression2 = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, property);

                ConstantExpression valueExpression1 = Expression.Constant(value1, typeof(DateTime));
                ConstantExpression valueExpression2 = Expression.Constant(value2, typeof(DateTime));

                BinaryExpression binaryExpression1 = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(memberExpression1, valueExpression1);
                BinaryExpression binaryExpression2 = Expression.LessThan(memberExpression2, valueExpression2);

                var ret1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(binaryExpression1, parameterExpression);
                var ret2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(binaryExpression2, parameterExpression);

                Expression and = Expression.And(ret1, ret2);

                result = result!=null?Expression.OrElse(result, and):and;   
            }
            return Expression.Lambda < Func<T,bool>>(result, parameterExpression);
}
```

And later in your code, you could do something like this:

```
var rangeExp=RangeExpression<Deal>("CloseDate",criteria.DateRanges);
deals = deals.Where(rangeExp);
```