# How to find a row where all search terms are contained within selected columns using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

For context, this question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36703908/64279) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36722610/64279). In this case, the user can specify an array of phrases. I'd like to expand upon the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36725662/64279) by asking how I can create a generic way to find entities where *all* the words of *any* of the phrases are contained within *any* of the specified columns.

To give you a better idea of what I'm talking about, if I were going to write this as a non-generic method, it would look something like this:

```
var searchPhrases = new [] {"John Smith", "Smith Bob"};
var searchTermSets = searchPhrases.Select(x => x.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

contacts.Where(c =>
    searchTermSets.Any(searchTerms =>
        searchTerms.All(searchTerm =>
            c.FullName.Contains(searchTerm)
            || c.FirstName.Contains(searchTerm)
            || c.LastName.Contains(searchTerm))));
```

What I'm trying to do is make an extension method where I can do something like this:

```
contact.WhereIn(
    searchPhrases,
    c => c.FullName,
    c => c.FirstName,
    c => c.LastName);
```

And the extension method signature would look something like this:

```
IQueryable<T> WhereIn<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<string> searchPhrases, params Expression<Func<T, string>>[] propertySelectors)
```

I tried following the same pattern from the previous questions I linked to, but I didn't get very far. That call to `All()` is tripping me up.

Comment: why don't you make a computed prop in your model and concatenate all search fields, then you do not need a multiple expressions? `public string SearchFields=>$"{FullName} {FirstName} {LastName}"`?

Comment: I don't know how many records you have in your db, but it you want to blow up your server... That is exactly the queries that can do it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression like the predicate for

```
contacts.Where(c =>
    searchTermSets.Any(searchTerms =>
        searchTerms.All(searchTerm =>
            c.FullName.Contains(searchTerm)
            || c.FirstName.Contains(searchTerm)
            || c.LastName.Contains(searchTerm))));
```

can be build dynamically with `Expression.Call` to `Enumerable.Any` and `Enumerable.All`.

First we'll need a simple parameter replacer so we can bind all the passed `Expression<Func<T, string>>` to a single parameter:

```
public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Then the implementation could be like this:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereIn<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<string> searchPhrases, params Expression<Func<T, string>>[] propertySelectors)
    {
        var searchTermSets = searchPhrases.Select(x => x.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        var c = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "c");
        var searchTerms = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string[]), "searchTerms");
        var searchTerm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "searchTerm");
        var allCondition = propertySelectors
            .Select(propertySelector => (Expression)Expression.Call(
                propertySelector.Body.ReplaceParameter(propertySelector.Parameters[0], c),
                "Contains", Type.EmptyTypes, searchTerm))
            .Aggregate(Expression.OrElse);
        var allPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(allCondition, searchTerm);
        var allCall = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Enumerable), "All", new[] { typeof(string) }, 
            searchTerms, allPredicate);
        var anyPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<string[], bool>>(allCall, searchTerms);
        var anyCall = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new[] { typeof(string[]) },
            Expression.Constant(searchTermSets), anyPredicate);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(anyCall, c);
        return source.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

The problem is though that it doesn't work. If you try to run your non generic query, you'll get `EntityCommandCompilationException` with inner `NotSupportedException` saying

> The nested query is not supported. Operation1='Case' Operation2='Collect'

The same will happen with the dynamically built query.

So what should we do? Well, taking into account that `searchPhrases` (thus `searchTermSets` and `searchTerms`) are known, we can treat them as constants, and all we need to get the desired result is to replace `Any` with `Or` expressions and `All` with `And` expressions.

The working solution looks like this (using the same parameter replacer):

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereIn<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<string> searchPhrases, params Expression<Func<T, string>>[] propertySelectors)
    {
        var searchTermSets = searchPhrases.Select(x => x.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        var c = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "c");
        var body = searchTermSets
            .Select(searchTerms => searchTerms
                .Select(searchTerm => propertySelectors
                    .Select(propertySelector => (Expression)Expression.Call(
                        propertySelector.Body.ReplaceParameter(propertySelector.Parameters[0], c),
                        "Contains", Type.EmptyTypes, Expression.Constant(searchTerm)))
                    .Aggregate(Expression.OrElse))
                .Aggregate(Expression.AndAlso))
            .Aggregate(Expression.OrElse);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, c);
        return source.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```